# Importing PowerShell binary modules from network location

Tags: networking, powershell, module

I have a network with several computers on it, and I'd like to put all my PowerShell modules in a network share so I can easily access them from any computer. This works for script modules, however binary modules don't seem to work.

The `Import-Module` statement can execute just fine without errors, however when you use `Get-Module`, it will show that the newly imported binary module is not exporting any Cmdlets. If I copy the module to a local directory on my computer, it all works as expected.

Is there a way to import binary modules from a network location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I found to load PowerShell modules was to add a configuration file to the `$PSHOME` directory.

I created a text file at `$PSHOME\powershell.exe.config` and put the following in the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>
        <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
    </startup>
    <runtime>
        <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

This does two things:

1. Uses [supportedRuntime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4atty68.aspx) to ensure that PowerShell runs under .NET 4.0 rather than .NET 3.5. This is important because .NET 4 has different security policies that are easier to understand and configure.
2. Uses [loadFromRemoteSources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409252.aspx) (only available in .NET 4+) to enable loading DLLs from remote locations such as a network file share.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry I know this question is old, but thought it would be useful to provide an answer for PowerShell v3. I had this same problem in PowerShell v3, and using Phil's answer was able to resolve it - with a minor modification.

PowerShell v3 already uses .NET 4.0, so I only actually needed the loadFromRemoteSources sections. So my `$PSHOME\powershell.exe.config` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Simple! Thanks Phil for the pointers, would upvote your answer but I don't have the reputation yet.